# MS CRM 2011 javascript consuming JSON service

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a JSON web service running that I can hit from a browser and get some simple data.
I'm trying to populate a CRM form with this data using some javascript (with jquery). The script fires on form load, and here's what it looks like:

```
function execute()
{
alert("start");

$.ajax({
  url: "http://myFancyService",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json",
  failure: function (msg) {
    alert("didn't work");
  },
  success: function (success) {
    alert("worked");
  }
});

alert("end");
}
```

I have added jQuery 1.9.1 as a web resource, and I call "isNaN" on form load.
The issue is that the ajax call seems to do nothing. I see the "start" alert, and then the "end" alert, and nothing in between. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are missing elements in your call, check this example code:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet",
        data: "{}",
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            alert("");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's from the microsoft samples for communicating with the CRM service. I'm not trying to do that, I'm contacting a much simpler custom service. In any event, adding contentType and header attributes didn't do anything. And mainly I don't understand why I see neither "worked" nor "didn't work" alerts.

Comment: No @Egor this is not specific for CRM Service this is a generic call to webservice using jquery. You can see this [article](http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/creating-a-webservice-proxy-with-jquery/) that explain each property. At least type is necessary. This you check with fiddler for example what request is sended.

Comment: So I was showing this to some other guy, and he said "why do you have "failure:" rather than "error:" in the ajax call?". And apparently it was as simple as that. So you were right in a way that I was missing an element. However, I didn't need to specify type or anything else, since I'm using "GET". Replacing "failure:" with "error:" made everything work.